# How to get php DOMDocument xpath of a select tag by name

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I have the following html:

```
<select type="text" name="City" value="">
<option>city1</option>
<option>city2</option>
<option>city3</option>
```

i am trying to use DOMDocument's xpath to get the array of the cities. my xpath expression so far is:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodeList = $xpath->query("//select[name=='City']/option");
```

This is not working and i can not figure out why.

Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$nodeList = $xpath->query("//select[@name='City']/option");
```